# RSS feed for responses to your posts

Tags: support, feed, responses, yahoo-pipes

**2009-01-29:** Due to website changes these pipes no longer work. Check out [https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/{user-id}](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/1) (or write a pipe for it).

---

Thanks to [Beau Simensen's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21756/rss-feed-for-responses-to-your-posts/21757#21757) I've fixed the [Yahoo! pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Pipes). Please feel free to use it.
http://pipes.yahoo.com/lanzkron/stackoverflow_responses

[Sam Hasler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541/sam-hasler) cloned [his own version](http://pipes.yahoo.com/flenser/stackoverflow%20responses%20with%20comment%20answer%20in%20title) that adds **commented:** or **answered:** to the title. <sub>(I'm not updating mine since it'll flood current subscribers with all the items again.)</sub>

It seems to work OK now. If you have enhancement requests or comments, please leave your comments here and I should by *magically* notified by RSS...

---

(original question follows)

---

Following a question about [how to be notified about responses to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392757/stackoverflow-easy-way-to-know-if-someone-replied-to-your-question#392772) I started writing a Yahoo! pipe to scrape the responses tab of the profile page (`https://stackoverflow.com/users/<so-id>?sort=responses`).

Sadly, getting pipes' regex to do what I thought it should do proved harder than I first anticipated.

Happily my wife gave birth last week.

Sadly this cut into the spare time I had to fool around on non-work/family related stuff.

So if you have the time please let me know how to fix [my pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/lanzkron/stackoverflow_responses). At the moment it has the following issues:

- None of the regular expressions work (even though they do on [REGex TESTER](http://www.regextester.com/))

  - **title:** Contents of second link (`^.*?</a>(.*?</a>).*`)
  - **link:**  Second HREF (`.*?href="[^"]*".*href="?([^"]*)".*`)
  - **author:** Text of first link (`^[^>]*>([^<]*)</a.*`)
- New items will appear several times since the time of the response changes (from *yesterday* to *2 days ago*, etc.). I think this is related to the **title** issue, but I'm not sure.

Also, this is the first time I'm creating an RSS feed, so I may be missing some other obvious stuff. If so, please let me know, and I'll add it.

Comment: The pipe linked to at the top of the question doesn't work, is it supposed to?

Comment: Sam, the link at the top of the page works for me what seems to be the problem?

Comment: the link works, but the pipe doesn't produce the same feed as Beau's when I clone it. I was expecting it to be fixed with Beau's changes.

Comment: The recent tab was replaced by http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/{your-user-id}. But it neither has a feed nor a Yahoo! Pipe. Who will create one for us?

Comment: I don't think anyone can write a pipe for it, you can only see your own recent page thus the pipe will not have access to your data :o(

Comment: someone can create an application that with your password can get the cookies that enables it to fetch the data periodically.

Comment: As Jeff mentioned in the SO blog, closing a question is effectively nominating it for deletion. There's no way this question should ever be deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took a swing at this. I never used [Yahoo! Pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Pipes) before, so it was a bit of a bear. I cloned your Pipe and updated it. You can take a look [my pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/kirkryyn/0fcc9da7a12aef80588cb88b0dff1097) here.

- **title:** (?s).*?<a.*?<a.+?>([^<]+).*
- **author:** (?s).*?<a([^>]+)>([^<]+?)</a>.*
- **link:** (?s).*?<a.*?<a.*?href="([^"]*).*
- **description:** (?s).*?<a.*?<a.+?>([^<]+).*?<p>(.+?)</p>

Replace with $1 for title, $2 for author, $1 for link and $2 for description.

I got a pointer from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360492/regular-expression-on-yahoo-pipes), stating that some of the checkboxes do not work correctly. I had the "s" checked initially, but it only seemed to work half the time, so things seemed very inconsistent.

From the link posted above:

> Somehow the case-insensitive checkbox
> seems broken. Luckily you can
> substitute with (?i), which works
> nicely.

So I tried to do the same with `s` to see if it worked like `i`, and sure enough. Honestly, I don't know this syntax very well (never seen it before), but it works so I was happy enough with that!

Comment: What are the (?s) at the start doing?

Comment: Updated my answer with more details on the (?s) thing, but essentially it is just forcing the same functionality as the s checkbox. I will have to look this up in more detail sometime.

Answer (score 4):

I have come up with a very clean solution for this that uses the API.

Here is the feed:

> `http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/{sites}/users/{ID}/mentioned`

Example of all recent comments made to Jeff Atwood on Stack Overflow:

http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/stackoverflow/users/1/mentioned

Comment: Link is 404.  Any chance for an update?

Comment: The link is broken: *"Not Found. The requested resource was not found on this server."*

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to know whether items were comments or answers, so I altered [my own clone of the pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/flenser/stackoverflow%20responses%20with%20comment%20answer%20in%20title)

```
In        item.title  
replace   (?s).*?<a.*?<(?:b|span[^>]+)>(comment|answer)(?:ed on|ed)?<.(?:b|span)>\s<a.+?>([^<]+).*  
with      $1: $2
```

This gives me titles like this:

> comment: Responses RSS Feed?
> comment: Responses RSS Feed?
> answer: RSS feed for responses to your Stack Overflow posts
> comment: What are the disadvantages of arrays?
> answer: Comparing cold-start to warm start
> answer: Where do Java and .NET string literals reside?

**Update:** I filed a [UserVoice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UserVoice#History) request yesterday to have [direct link to comments on recent, responses, and user feed](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/99851-direct-link-to-comments-on-recent-responses-user-feed) which is currently under review and would make it much easier go to comments when they appear in the feed if it is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

**Native RSS feed for responses**

Combine `user feed` with `/responses`

For example:

- `https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/`your-user-id`/responses`
- `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/`your-user-id`/responses`

To get the user feed for any domain:

1. Go to your account profile
2. Check for "user feed" at the bottom
3. add `/responses` to the URL