# SO's lack of documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, meta-faq

Given the barrage of downvotes because I could not find something on meta that apparently everyone thought I should know, I would like to mention what I see is a serious disconnect in the organization of documentation on SO from what is intuitive.

First, the only form of documentation *on SO* is a FAQ. FAQ as the sole form of documentation is sorely inadequate. Q&A (of which a FAQ is variant) is not the same as a book and one form cannot replace the other. Wikis for example, are not laid out in a Q&A fashion. SO really needs a site that outlines, for example the *current* rules (and all the rules) with respect to Reputation. There are many questions on meta about reputation but the algorithm has evolved over time and there is no easy place to get that answer. Similarly, getting to information on bounties is really buried which brings me to my next point.

The usability of the FAQ is awful unless your question solely relates to the 15 questions they list. For example, let's say you are trying to determine *when* a bounty is subtracted from your reputation (the question whose answer everyone thought I should know). Go to the SO FAQ page and notice there is nothing on the right panel of questions related to bounties. Do a search, in your browser, for "bounty". Nothing, go fish. Under questions? Go fish. Under reputation? Go fish. What if I don't get a good answer? Huzah! However, there is nothing that indicates that the moment the bounty is opened that the bounty amount is subtracted from their reputation (only that it eventually will be subtracted). Now the user has to go to fish on meta. That brings me to the third point.

It is counter-intuitive to be required to navigate to an entirely different site for documentation on the site you left. Most people assume meta is for people asking questions about designing a SE site not general questions that they would have found in documentation had it existed in a Wiki form.

Meta does not work well IMO as documentation nor is it designed to be that. It is designed as Q&A. However, many questions could be avoided if there was an actual documentation store like a wiki (Not a FAQ. Not Q&A). One reason for that is that questions are asked over time and the "right" answer changes over time (e.g. Reputation algorithm, daily cap algorithm). It is cumbersome to find the last "correct" answer.

So, SO really needs a wiki and more importantly they need to keep it current so that it is versioned along with the site.

Comment: I can't really disagree with the man... +1

Comment: What are your plans for the wiki to not also become a morass like you say the FAQ is now?

Comment: @random - A fair question. The documentation should be based on how the site actually works and thus only the people that can alter how the site works should be updating it.

Comment: SE does not have anyone willing to keep the documentation up to date and they're even being paid. The community stepped up and that's why you have the FAQ.

Comment: @random - I presume there are developers that are implementing feature requests and making changes. If no one else, they would be logical people to update the Wiki when an algorithm is changed.

Comment: Maybe SE needs to start paying someone to do the documentation then? I've been thinking that for a long time.

Comment: I would think that documentation would be an avenue to improve the questions on meta by reducing the odds (not eliminating of course) of them being asked in the first place.

Comment: Your belief that people read even a well formatted document is laudable, but experience and the horrors of Meta prove it's misguided

Comment: @random At least you would have a clear document/location to slap them over the head with if they ask something answered there. This instead of a random, hard to find earlier asked question not part of the current FAQ.

Comment: @random you're right, there will always be a huge audience who will not read anything they're presented. But there is a minority that is really willing to look stuff up. You have to admit they are given a *very* imperfect place for that - Meta. Meta may be a substitute for proper documentation for us veterans, but it's not for someone new to the system.

Comment: @MikeB *["What are they being paid for then?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+bug)*?

Comment: BTW--I'm not usually very sympathetic to these kinds of complaints, but I'll admit that this one is hard to search.

Comment: @Random: perhaps true :) but our questioner appears to be arguing for documentation for himself rather than plaintively whining that _others_ don't read the existing documentation. I can empathize.

Comment: Documenting *everything* that happens on an SE site would be a *huuuuge* wiki. Even wikipedia's own documentation is actually fairly difficult to navigate. Hell, just look at their [getting started page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Contents/Getting_started). It's a sea of blue links and it's really hard to find your relevant info. I find it hard to believe any SE wiki would be easier to read than the current FAQ, but it sure would be a lot harder to impliment and a much bigger context shift.

Comment: @Pekka I'd have to be convinced this was actually a wide-spread issue before I could see putting resources behind it, personally. The only failing of the FAQ entry in this particular case is that it doesn't use the word "immediately" in the description, requiring you to visit the privileges page to find that out. There's probably some issue with all of the entries being collapsed (and thus unsearchable) by default, but the bounty dialog does have a "learn more..." link that takes you right to the appropriate section.

Comment: The [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) on meta has most of it

Comment: Honestly, it seems *the entirety of your argument* is based around you not finding *one bit of information* about bounties. That's really not a good reason to make earth-shattering changes. it's also something extremely easy to learn by doing, and not nearly catastrophic for the user.

Comment: @BenBrocka - If that's the case, then there is a disconnect in our understanding. This isn't the only time I've look for information about something on SO and couldn't find it *on SO*. Rather, you have to go to an entirely different site whose purpose isn't really about instructing SO works but rather about how to tweak the design of the SE sites. Another good example is the reputation algorithms or the daily cap algorithms. If the information is already *on SO*, then we're talking about another way to get to the same information. Clearly others want a wiki too.

Comment: @Ephraim - The key is *on meta*. I bet you that most SO users have no idea what "meta" is or they think it's about design and not help about using SO. While I'm find with meta being about discussions for *how* SO *should* work, SO should wholly contain its own documentation about how to use its site. Why isn't there a "meta meta" for how to use the meta.stackoverflow site? Clearly, some of the information and perhaps what I'm seeking is what many others seek which is a different way getting to that info.

Comment: @Thomas It's not an "entirely different site", it's a subdomain. I'm completely not seeing what the difference is between the current meta and your "wiki" idea, other than calling it something besides "meta" and blocking regular users from editing it. I'm not sure why you think restricting updates to only developers will somehow make the information more up-to-date than the current system where developers and regular users can maintain the documentation together; judging from posts like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445), developers aren't very interested in keeping docs updated

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - You are asking multiple items here. First, Meta is a Q&A site and looks and feels entirely different than SO by design. It is disjoint to a user to navigate to a radically different view for help. That different view is intentional as meta has a different purpose and focus than SO. It is akin to being directed to the employee breakroom to ask what aisle the olive oil is located.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - Second, meta's purpose is Q&A not documentation. It is being shoe-horned to act like documentation yet it has a serious deficiency which is versioning. Find the current rules on the daily cap on meta. There are lots of questions about this and the rules have changed. It might be the case that the highest voted answer is no longer current. I shouldn't have to fish through responses to get  to the current rules. The issue is finding the docs. There is no single place for this on SO. You have go fish on the faq, "just know" to use the "privileges" link or go fish on meta.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek -Third, the developers are the ones that truly know how a changes actually work. Thus, barring dedicated folks, they are the ones that will know how to change the docs to fit the new rules. When a feature is implemented, if someone other than the developer that implements the feature knows exactly how it will work and can convey that in the docs, then great. However, others stated that even these people do not have time for this. Apparently, no one has time for documentation.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - Lastly, your link is a perfect example of the problem. If you are on SO, how would you find this page? If you search for "feature changes" on meta, there are dozens of answers. As a user, I shouldn't have to fish through those responses and deduce which one is actually current to get to the release history. We're talking about the difference between MSDN and forums. Just having a link to "help" in SO that goes to a list of topics in SO which I could search with my browser would be useful since it appears lots of the documentation exists but requires a bit of voodoo to find.

Comment: @Thomas I realize developers are the ideal people to do it; I'm saying they probably won't, so converting meta to a wiki the rest of us can't edit probably won't end well. Don't block the only people that actually do keep things up to date from doing so. As for making a help link, there's an [FAQ index](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites); would you just want that linked directly from SO?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - RE: Developers, I agree so if that's the case typically it falls to another person dedicated with keeping the docs current. Devs don't want to do documentation. Other users don't have time. We're back to no official documentation. RE: FAQ: I guess I don't understand why that FAQ list is on meta at all. Why isn't it and all of its article contents on SO's FAQ?

Comment: @Thomas Because it would make the main FAQ like 500 pages long. The main FAQ is for brand-new users who have questions like "how does rep work", not for detailed breakdowns of everything that can happen. Until SEI actually hires someone whose sole job is documentation, let's not shut off the only form of documentation that currently exists because you had trouble finding something. Make it easier to search, link to it from the main FAQ, whatever; but let's not get rid of it entirely in favor of an idealized system where the docs are always up to date and all information is found without effort

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - Something else I see in the articles on the FAQ index (which I did not know existed. Ty!). Which of these are official SO policy/procedure and which of these are really good opinions that mgmt might consider or embrace? E.g., the question on the spam flag (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work). Is that how it actually works or is that how someone thinks it works and how do we know the difference? How did the top responder know how it works? Are we saying that the best responses are automatically SO/meta official policy or position?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - TBH, I'm more interested in the official docs on how things work rather than a Q&A or a FAQ. I'm looking for a help page by subject matter not a FAQ. Thus, "the best way to answer a question" wouldn't be something I would see in the docs necessarily. "The rules governing the daily cap" would.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - Btw, at no time did I ever suggest eliminating meta. Meta has its purpose as Q&A. What I'm saying is that Q&A as the only form of official documentation is insufficient.

Comment: This kind of feels like [my lukewarmly received feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110180/131713) for improving the FAQ, taken to the next level.

Answer (score 14):

A great many features of the site are unlocked via [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) -- and the best documentation of those features is often the descriptions there. For example, under the **set bounties** privilege you'll find the following text block:

> What happens when I place a bounty?
>
> - The question is immediately bumped to the top of the active question list.
> - The question gets placed in the home page's featured tab for seven days.
> - **The reputation you're using for the bounty is immediately and irreversibly deducted from your reputation.**
> - If your new reputation brings you below the requirement for any privileges, you will lose access to those privileges.

(I have made bold the portion you were curious about, simply to follow the example.)

The main difficulty is where to *find* the list of privileges -- it is hidden inside a mouse-over drop-down box that shows when you hover your mouse pointer over your username in the header (or click the little triangle next to your username):

> [image: location of the privileges link]

Perhaps this list of privileges could be made more prominent.

I think I've only found one instance when the documentation in the privileges section was not corrected for a [recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) -- by and large, this documentation *is* kept up-to-date.

Comment: The bounty privileges page is actually linked from the FAQ entry that the [dialog used to start a bounty links to](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bOIP9.png), even. I suppose it could save a click by being a bit more explicit about the immediate reputation deduction in the FAQ entry itself, by inserting "immediately" into "you will *always* give up the amount of reputation specified in the bounty".

Comment: I didn't even know this existed, so thanks! I agree this could be made more prominent- perhaps a big flashing anigif on the FAQ leading to the priviliges page? (Or you know, just a hyperlink)

Comment: Been using SO for a couple of years now, I had no idea that from privileges were extended documentation such as this. Wouldn't have ever thought to look there and as far as I know, the search on the site won't crawl these pages. In the FAQ section on bounties, there is no link to this page.

Comment: There is however a link in the section on reputation. Still, nice to know there is another area with some documentation even if it is well hidden.

Comment: @Thomas There *is* a link to the privileges page with bounty information in the [bounty FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty). It's the one with the text "offering a bounty" (second paragraph).

Comment: @TimStone - I don't see a link the bounty entry. The only link I see to privileges in the Reputation section.

Comment: @Thomas these privileged pages are shown to you via a notification bar message immediately after you unlock them now.

Comment: Jeff Atwood calls this "Just-in-Time Documentation;" providing the user with only the information they need, when they need it.  I am a huge fan.  People won't read a manual, but they'll read a small bit of text at the time a new feature appears.

Comment: @Ben, yeah, but most people won't post a bounty the day they get the privilege...

Comment: @TimStone - OIC. Sorry. You have to go through "offering a bounty" which takes you to meta (which I also discussed. Shouldn't have to navigate way from SO for documentation on SO).

Comment: @Robert: You never laid awake in bed at night with a large manual for some new toy that you really wanted to know _all about_? :)

Comment: @BenBrocka - Would never (didn't actually) have thought to look at privileges to find help on bounties.

Comment: @sarnold: Not in a long time.  When I was a kid I did that, but the ADHD nature of modern software development has pretty much destroyed that part of my brain.  Everything I own that I know how to use (other than my computer) has one button on it. :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey - The problem with JIT documentation is that you have to outguess the user as to the subject which they seek. IMO, it is not a replacement for a real wiki which can be search and isn't Q&A.

Comment: @Thomas What? The "offering a bounty" link takes you to [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties), which is on Stack Overflow, and lists out all of the rules related to bounties (including the fact that "the reputation you're using for the bounty is immediately and irreversibly deducted from your reputation")

Comment: @Thomas: And the problem with regular documentation is you have to know what you're looking for for it to be of any use, unless you want to read the whole damn thing.

Comment: @TimStone - I see it now. Would never have thought to hit that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Which many users do. The solution isn't to only provide JIT help. The solution is to provide both. Do you only learn by using Google or do you read books too? The former is the equivalent of searching meta. A wiki is the equivalent of the latter. Where I can use the Table of Contents or Index to find the material I want.

Comment: Wow, they really need to make that privileges link more prominent. I actually knew that a lot of good documentation is hidden under privs, but honestly never could figure out how to get there. At first I always used Google "site:stackoverflow.com privileges whatever" to find the docs, until I just remembered that the page was at "/privileges". I never knew where the link to it was.

Comment: I guess it doesn't help me that I never click that little arrow next to my name, but I'm certainly not the only person that has no reason to. I never log out (fairly common, I'm sure), and when I want to see my details/summary/stats, I just click on my username or rep, never the arrow (again, probably fairly common).

Comment: Really, I think it needs to be added to the menu of other options on the user profile page, currently "summary answers questions tags badges favorites bounties reputation responses activity votes"

Comment: Just In Time documentation is great, but it can take you only so far. It can't satisfy  deeper interest in how the system works, or edge cases / problems.

Answer (score 7):

## How Stack Exchange is *currently* documented.

### Help Center

As of [June, 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center), all sites have high-level documentation created and maintained by Stack Exchange employees. The goal of this documentation is to be:

1. Clear
2. Up-to-date

However it does not make any claims at completeness. Help pages mostly cover common situations or explain how features work in broad strokes. So, you'll find [a list of badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) and a summary of how to earn them. But it's not the right place to find the [nitty gritty details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges), which are [subject to change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251172/should-we-change-the-positive-asking-record-criteria-for-the-curious-badge-set).

### Meta Stack Exchange

As of [April, 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014), questions applicable to all Stack Exchange sites may be asked and answered right here, on Meta Stack Exchange. (Before that date, Meta Stack Overflow served the same purpose.) We also encourage users to use per-site metas to document issues specific to individual sites. (Note: users are also free to ask about network-wide issues because we think of individual sites as [separate communities](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).) The goal of Meta to be:

1. Comprehensive
2. Clear

So people are encouraged to ask about edge cases they run into, obscure bugs, and help with nuanced use of our features. Our developers keep an eye on [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) questions. Many features are developed with input from [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) questions. Site policies often begin with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions. Just like our main Q&A sites, meta sites do a pretty good job of providing clear, concise answers to even the most long-tail of questions.

Editing is encouraged if you discover a mistake or outdated information. But there's a lot of historical information that never gets updated. (Remember the [orange bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notification-bar)?) We have tools such as duplicate closures, sidebar links, and the [meta FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) that reduce confusion to a degree. Even so, everytime a developer changes some code there's a chance information on meta will go out of date.

### JIT Help

We make heavy use of documentation embedded in our user interface, which is often referred to as [JIT documentation](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-just-in-time-theory/). Like our help center, these bits of documentation are intended to be clear and up-to-date. They also give us the rare opportunity to include details that the user needs right at that moment. Most people won't care that Stack Exchange OpenID restricts users from using their email as a password. But for those few who try it, we let them know right then and there:

[image: JIT help]

### Chat, comments, blogs, podcasts, developer talks, email, etc. and so on

Finally, we have about a dozen other places to disseminate information. We strive for clarity and accuracy, but not every medium affords the same level of each. As much as I love our podcasts, it can often be difficult to figure out which bits are jokes, which are wild speculations that will never see the light of day, and which are items that people should pay attention to. Our blog posts tend to be more clear (I hope!) but we don't do much to keep them up-to-date. (Well, other than ones we cite all the time.) Chat items and comments become obsolete. At best outdated comments will get deleted. You'll just have to use your common sense with these miscellaneous channels.

Why do we have all these channels? Every month, we have company-wide meeting with a standard set of announcements. One of them is "Default Public", which means "Unless there's a good reason not to, we should be saying and doing things in public". We fall short of that goal often, but nearly every day someone will say something like "Shouldn't that be a meta post ... or something?"

### The *Mythical Man Month* is still worth reading

The [*Mythical Man Month*](https://archive.org/details/mythicalmanmonth00fred) concludes with a chapter called "The Other Face" that explains how to write documentation for users. I want to summarize every single point in that chapter, but you can read it yourself. I *will* use that chapter to set up an association between traditional software documentation and our documentation:

- Map of the forest: [the tour page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour)
- How to use Stack Exchange: [the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help)
- Detailed test cases: [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)
- Flow charts: we don't have those
- Self-documenting programs: tool-tips, badges, pop ups, banners, notifications, user profiles, *et al*.

For those who are wondering about the missing comprehensive, "here's how every part works in detail" documentation, I strongly suggest you read "The Flow-Chart Curse" section in Fred Brooks' book. That said, I think there might be room for a wiki that fills any gaps between the help center and meta. I'm worried, however, that a wiki would try to fill the flow chart gap, which would largely be a waste.

Answer (score 5):

> So, SO really needs a wiki and more importantly they need to keep it current so that it is versioned along with the site.

SO does not need a wiki. The information (more or less) exists; what SO needs is better *cataloging* of that information. JIT-style documentation is nice, but only if you're about to use it right then. If you need to look something up, it's a lot less user-friendly because there is **no other alternative**.

Comment: you could build a proper catalog in the faq tag wiki, if it becomes awesome we can promote it better

Comment: @waffles - That would requires users A. know to go to meta and B. know to search for the FAQ tag. Neither of those are intuitive.

Comment: + 1 I would agree that a better organization of the existing information *placed on SO* would work. That information should include the official, current rules (as opposed to best answer) on the daily cap algorithm, the rep effect of down votes (which has changed over time), the consolidated list of items that effect reputation etc.

Answer (score 3):

I started something a long time ago on WikiBooks:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/The_StackExchange_User_Guide (yes, I know - there is supposed to be a space between "Stack" and "Exchange")

Perhaps we could encourage the community to start adding some more content?

Comment: Figure out how to give points for edits...

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't feel we need a catalog that encompasses every nuance of the system. People hate reading big books, what they want is answers to specific questions.

We try hard to give you "just in time" documentation, though we can do a better job refining the system. When you get a new badge, we tell you why you got it and what it means. When you get a privilege, we tell you what it is and what it implies. When you run out of votes we let you know what your daily limit is, and so on.

---

Take your bounty example, when you click "start a bounty", you are presented with the text:

> offer [50] of my own reputation for an answer to this question

There is even a link to more information. This can really only be interpreted in one way.

Now, if you are afraid to click "start a bounty" cause you think something disastrous is going to happen, and really think it should be "start a bounty..." instead, it is a topic for a separate discussion (so we can address it by itself)

Similarly, if you think that 1 rep users should still see the link, it is a subject for another discussion.

---

Another couple of concrete improvements I think could help in this area are "duplicate handling" and "improved search". Both are on our roadmap.

I am not against improving "tag wikis" and perhaps the "tags" page on meta or sidebar, but I think we need to focus on small concrete changes here.

Comment: "Now, if you are afraid to click 'start a bounty' cause..." What if you don't click that button because it doesn't make sense to you that the way to learn about how bounties work is to *try to make one*? It's not a question of *fear*; it's a question of, "it never occurred to me." In general, documentation is not found by trying to do something; it's found by looking for documentation. JIT documentation only works when you are actively trying to do something. If you're just looking for information (perhaps in preparation for doing something), it doesn't work.

Comment: @NicolBolas in that case we could change it to "start a bounty (learn more)" for people with a small amount of rep

Comment: That still misses the point. I wouldn't necessarily even be *looking* at a question when I think "I want to learn about bounties."

Comment: @NicolBolas People are probably going to be looking for information about how bounties work when they a) see a bounty offered, or b) want to offer a bounty themselves. In both of these cases they'll be given hyperlinks to more information about bounties. I don't imagine people will be unable to sleep wondering about how SO bounties work unless they either *see* a bounty or *want to create* a bounty.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst: How will we know if they're thinking about offering a bounty? It's not like that link will just magic itself into their brain when they are wondering about offering a bounty. Again, the may not be looking at the question at the moment. When I think "find info on X", my first thought doesn't go to "press the button to cause X to happen." My first thought goes to the upper-right area of the screen. It's useful to tell people how a system works when you're about to use it, but it's *also* useful for people to find that information when they're looking for it.

Comment: "people hate reading big books" - speak for yourself please