# Can something bad happen if questions I post are being put on hold a lot?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban, on-hold

On some Stack Exchange site I have two questions that are put on hold and may be closed soon.

I guess this will happen a lot, so does something bad happen when you ask questions that are put on hold and closed constantly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You might get question-banned.**

With enough closed or negatively-scoring questions, the system may decide that you're no longer trusted to post questions and automatically block you from doing so.

But don't panic! [According to Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252645/152859) (a Stack Exchange employee):

> - There are multiple, cooperating algorithms at work. Some of them result in permanent bans, others just apply stricter rate-limits to askers.
> - Not all questions are taken into account. Everyone makes mistakes; banning you for one would be unfair... Unless making mistakes is all you do here.
> - Well-received questions count for a lot. Really, any participation that demonstrates you're not a complete drain on the system helps in avoiding the ban.
> - Zero-scored posts don't help at all. This isn't some MMO where you can grind your way to victory by mindless clicking; someone has to find your work useful.
> - The faster you're posting questions, the faster you'll get banned if those questions aren't well-received. Given it takes some amount of time for even well-written questions to attract attention, if you're hitting the rate-limits for questions per day/month and aren't also dripping with upvotes you should probably be somewhat concerned.

Comment: FWIW system is designed to [warn users approaching the ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118/165773)

Comment: Huh, missed the source in the initial revision! :/