# What does "positively received" mean in the conditions for lifting a question ban?

Tags: support, post-ban

The [FAQ post about post ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) mentions that it's possible to post one more question after a six-months waiting period and if the question is good enough, the question ban can be lifted:

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask *one* new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

What is *positively received* in this context? Is it enough if the question has a zero score and is not closed? Or does it have to have a positive score?

How long does the system wait after posting this new question to evaluate this criteria and possibly lift (or reinstate) the question ban?

Comment: *"Is it enough if the question has zero score"* - no, it needs to have net positive score. See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262814/3001761

Comment: The system isn't lifting or reinstating a quality ban. It checks when you post a question if you meet the quality ban criteria. If you do, the question is rejected. Users in a q-ban can always ask a question every 6 months after their last question (deleted and non-deleted). Quality banned users shouldn't rely on that one question becoming well received (stays open, receives upvotes). Passively waiting for a q-ban to expire is the wrong strategy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does the question ban get applied?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252046/when-does-the-question-ban-get-applied)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: Neither of the proposed duplicates addresses the specific issue here, what does "positively received" mean in the context of the once-in-6-months allowed Question under an existing ban.  One of the two does not mention this phrase, and the other proposed duplicate merely mentions it without clarification.  In other contexts (earning badges) "positively received" can mean at least two (net) upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, there is no "special" consideration for that one question. The system will simply consider that one question along with one's other questions, and check to see if the user overall no longer meets the ban criteria.

There was a case a while back where a user had been banned due to asking low-quality questions many years earlier. Once they restarted using the site, they found themselves affected by the 6-month rate limit. They went on to ask *really* good questions every six months, but due to their prior activity years earlier, were still unable to get out of the ban despite asking great questions. (In the end, the SE team noticed their trend of great questions and offered to dissociate some of their old, bad questions from their account, and they now have a fully-working account.)