# Why am I not being awarded the curious badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

The post explains well that you get the [curious badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/263251) when you have a positive question record:

> A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is **(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5**. Questions that have been downvoted and closed and deleted count three times in this calculation!

Then this [request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251172/should-we-change-the-positive-asking-record-criteria-for-the-curious-badge-set) with [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) indicates that the new formula is:

> **(total questions - negative questions - closed - early deleted)/total questions >= 0.5**

Whereas early deleted refers to questions deleted in less than 60 days.

On my profile on skeptics.se, [I have asked 23 questions](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/20749/george-chalhoub) among which 2 are closed and 1 downvoted with [no early deleted questions](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/20749):

[image]

It is good to mention that that the *early deleted questions* page refer to questions deleted over [the past 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/263251):

> Answers tabs that'll list the given user's deleted questions or answers, currently limited to those posted in the past 60 days.

So, if you do the math:

> (23 - 6 - 3 - 0)/23 = 0.6 > 0.5

Also, it is obvious that the other requirement is met (Ask on separate days):

[image]

So, why am I not being awarded the curious badge?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That page only lists questions deleted in the past 60 days, not questions which were deleted within 60 days of being posted. You have 9 deleted questions, of which 4 were negatively scored, 6 were closed and all 9 were early deleted.

Your score:

`32 - 5 - 8 - 9 = 10 / 32 = 0.3125`