# Why is there no statute of limitations for the Explainer badge family for closed questions? Can it please be added?

Tags: feature-request, support, badges, closed-questions, edit-and-answer-badges

The Explainer, Refiner, and Illuminator badges (collectively, the edit and answer badge family) are awarded for answering and editing a question within 12 hours of each other, with the answer being positively scored. A requirement that's not noted in the system badge description is that [if the question is later closed, the answer will no longer count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/377214).

The reason behind this requirement is to prevent users from gaming the system and to discourage answering questions that fundamentally cannot be salvaged into a non-closeable state, as explained in the [announcement of these badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239898/377214).

However, there's no time limit for the closure check, which means that if a question is closed several *years* after the edit and answer, it will cease to count in the same manner as if the question was closed *just* afterwards. Generally, when a question is closed *years* after it is asked, it's not because it was low-quality in the first place, but because of other circumstances that don't reflect negatively on the question, e.g. the site's scope changed or the software version it's asking about has become outdated.

To account for this, there are statutes of limitations, i.e. provisions in which the system won't count a post negatively towards someone if a negative action took place a long time after it was originally posted:

- The asking days badges, which were [announced a few months before the edit and answer badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/377214), [don't consider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/377214) questions closed or deleted more than 60 days after being asked as "closed" or "deleted" toward their two checks.
- Questions that were deleted [more than 30 days after being asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97720/377214) aren't considered "deleted" for the purposes of question bans and rate limits.
- Posts that [were visible on the site for 60 or more days and score 3 or higher](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/) don't incur a reputation loss for the author if they are eventually deleted.

All of these statutes of limitations were defined before the edit and answer badge family was implemented. The point is, as the team has a history of implementing these, I find it unlikely that it was overlooked when discussing the criteria for edit and answer badges, and more likely that it was considered but ultimately decided not to implement.

1. If that's so, why was it decided not to implement a statute of limitations for closed questions for the edit and answer badges (e.g. make it so that questions closed 60+ days after the answer is posted don't deduct one's progress from the badge)? Is it a philosophical reason (i.e. a reason why if a question gets closed a long time later, users don't deserve to have their answer count), or is it, as Glorfindel commented, a technical reason?
2. If there's no philosophical reason for not implementing it, and there are no significant technical hurdles, can such a statute of limitations please be implemented? (e.g. if the question is closed more than 60 days after a qualifying answer, it won't be considered a "closed" question for the purposes of the badge)

Comment: Especially on Meta, where questions are routinely closed as "no longer reproducible", there should be a "statute of limitations" for all badges.

Comment: Quite a bit of unuseful overhead to not make this a feature request immediately, perhaps? If there's a good reason not to implement the request, it can be declined... and if you forget to turn it into a request or get no answer to this one (because honestly it's not that important for writing a request), this will forever be 'stuck' until someone else decides to post.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell If there weren't signals that this was considered and decided not to implement initially, I would have just filed this as a feature request. Since it probably was, it's better for a feature request to argue against those reasons. If I get no answer here, I can still file the request, simply stating that I asked this and got no answer, which will still help to show that I made research effort.

Comment: I have no inside information, but would not exclude these possibilities: 1) performance reasons 2) a desire to keep it simple (also called 'lazyness' :))

Comment: @Tinkeringbell After some consideration, I decided to turn it into a feature request.

Comment: @Sonic I don't think the existence of time limits on other badges is evidence that we consider it for every new badge that gets created. Someone brought it up in the discussion for the asking days badges. I'd strongly suspect that no one thought about it in these editing badges. We don't exactly have a comprehensive guide to making new badges that people refer to. Tl;dr Despite your desires that there is some underlying reason, it is most likely that it was not considered.

Comment: @animuson That answers number 1, and the very first part of number 2. But what about the rest of number 2: if there's no significant technical hurdle, can it please be implemented?