# How does an faq-proposed question become part of the FAQ?

Tags: support, meta-faq

There are 131 questions tagged [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed). The [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) says:

> **How can a question be added to this FAQ?**
>
> **Link back** to this index. Paste this at the end of the question:
>
> How can a question be added to this FAQ?
>
> - Link back to this index. Paste this at the end of the question:
>
>   `[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)`
> - Tag as [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) and [support](/questions/tagged/support). When a post seems to hit a mature state, it will have faq added by a moderator.
> - Flag for a moderator to mark **community wiki**. Any FAQ post not yet community wiki should be made into a community wiki.
> - Add a link in the above table of contents.
> - Ask only the question, stated plainly and simply, in the question    body. The answer goes in an answer.

Actually applying filters `[faq-proposed] [support] closed:0 url:*7931 wiki:1 answers:1`, the 131 [drops down to 9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfaq-proposed%5D+%5Bsupport%5D+closed%3A0+url%3A*7931+wiki%3A1+answers%3A1) :-); though I'm fairly sure that there are more that are worthy [(or at least ought to be)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying).

Having filled out the mundane criteria (doesn't mean the proposal is good just that it fulfils the search criteria!) the next stage is:

> When a post seems to hit a mature state, it will have faq added by a
>   moderator.

Is there anything less woolly than this?

[image]

Comment: Some questions, like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7954), are no longer relevant.

Comment: Others, like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86603), don't contain enough useful information to make it to [faq] status.  I would suggest removing the tag from those posts that clearly aren't faq-worthy, or whip them into shape so that they are.

Comment: Still others seem to duplicate content in other posts, so some consolidation is also in order.

Comment: Speaking of the current [meta-tag:faq] system being woolly: [Usability improvements to the community FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110180/usability-improvements-for-the-community-faq)

Comment: Worth noting: if you change your search to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[faq-proposed]+[support]+answers%3A1&submit=search), you get 54 entries.  Many  of the [faq-proposed] posts are not properly "productized."