# Add link to faq within error/warning message

Tags: feature-request, usability, error-message, meta-faq

I wanted to get the [boater hat](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/boater) and I wished there was a link to the FAQ in the error messages warning me that I was approaching my limit of votes per day and therefore would not be able to wear that pretty hat :'( .

More generally, wouldn't that be possible to just click on any error/warning messages and get to the appropriate FAQ page? That would be *really* nice for newcomers.

I view this as a complementary approach to the 
[Usability improvements for the community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110180/usability-improvements-for-the-community-faq)