# Include original Ask date on active tab

Tags: feature-request, timestamps, question-lists

When I'm browsing the active questions, it would be nice to see not only how long ago it was modified, but when it was originally asked.  Here's a mock up

[image]

EDIT:  I like seeing the creation date because I typically am not interested in really old threads.  My observation is that most of the time (this is in general, not absolute), younger threads are modified because they're still in the process of being discussed.  Older threads are modified to perform some kind of maintenance -- tag deletion/addition, or they just happen to be noticed by someone cleaning up old posts.  So I don't like wasting time on the latter cases.

Comment: Too cluttered in my opinion, I wouldn't like it.

Comment: Maybe a different font or layout or something.  Dropping the time would remove some of the clutter.  The mock up was just a starting suggestion.  I'm not a UI person.

Comment: Maybe adding this the tooltip,

Comment: Adding it to a tooltip would be acceptable.

Comment: Trouble is, the "modified" is the useful one. Bumped questions tend to be looked because of the thing which bumped it, and so the modified details and link are more useful than the original data/link. Tooltip might work tho

Comment: Can you explain why you want the creationdate as well? What makes you use that view differently or how does it improve your workflow if you have the creationdate available as well?

Comment: @rene Added that info to the post.

Comment: As per the @benisuǝqbackwards answer on [Why are all posts in “active” tab displayed as “modified”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260915/why-are-all-posts-in-active-tab-displayed-as-modified)  some new navigation is currently being tested. Can anyone with high-reps who have been approved confirm this. I am currently waiting to be part of the new navigation test group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like the idea - it does annoy me sometimes to find out the activity was simply a retag or similar, but I also agree with @ShadowWizard that your suggestion would be too cluttered.

So I made a userscript using @ShadowWizard's suggestion!

Hovering over the 'modified' (or similar) parts will show a tooltip with the asked date/time:

> [image]

The script simply gets the text from the box on the actual question page and adds it as a tooltip. It *does not* override the already-present exact UTC time that is displayed on hover - that will still appear if you hover over the *time*. Hovering over the *text* will show this new tooltip :)

### Install from [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/shu8/e96e44fe1e7f41eb22e7/raw/7d076bf3703d65fb6a5888bd1bf75cdf1af6d137/add-asked-date-tooltip.user.js)

If you're unsure on how to install userscripts, see the [guide at StackApps](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) :)

---

Note: this does not work on Community Wiki posts because I'm not using the API - and I don't think there is any point using the API for such a small use case. The reason this doesn't work is because it sends a GET request to the question page, and extracts the 'asked' date that is shown in the blue box under the question - but this doesn't exist on CW posts :(

Comment: Current tooltip is showing exact UTC time, so better append the "asked" date, not overwrite - the exact time is useful many times.

Comment: @ShadowWizard if you hover over the actual time (eg. `7 hours ago` in the above screenshot), you will still see the exact UTC time... It only adds the tooltip to the 'modified' text.

Comment: huh! very clever. :)

Comment: Why would be more important the question's date thant the last **activity**? Maybe you want not be "bothered" by minor edits (ie: retag) but, what about a new answer? I would prefer to see the date of the last answer (instead of the date of the question).

Comment: @BlasSoriano well if it was a new answer, it would say `answered`, but `modified` could mean anything from closure, reopening, retagging, editing, etc..

Comment: Looks good.  I'm still going to leave this open for a bit (maybe 1 more day?) to see if others having something else to offer.   I think showing a post as having an accepted answer dissuades some people from contributing to it.  Thanks!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I see, thanks. Maybe you could examine why it is not working on some entries, like for example [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21756/rss-feed-for-responses-to-your-posts).

Comment: @BlasSoriano I just had a look and unfortunately that's not going to work - because if the post has been edited, the asked date isn't shown directly on the page and I don't think there's any point using the API for something so small... :( Sorry.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ That would be ok for wikis; what about this question (the one I'm commenting in just now)? it also does not show the tooltip, and it isn't a wiki.

Comment: @BlasSoriano works for me: http://i.imgur.com/9ipW728.png

Comment: That's weird. It worked for me too after refreshing the page twice. If it just this, don't worry (too minor issue). Thanks again